# Where can I download the older iPhone OS 3.1 SDK?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is it possible to still download the iPhone OS 3.1 SDK?  If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just install the 3.2 SDK. The 3.0 and 3.1 SDKs are included in it.

If you really need the old versions, there is a list of links in. http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html

Comment: can you provide me some link from where i can get the mac os 10.5.8

Comment: @uttam: Check "Software Update". Or directly buy 10.6.