# iphone sdk 3.0 requirements

Tags: iphone, macos

I have Mac OS X 10.5.8 and wanted to get its compatible iphone sdk version. i got iphone sdk 3.2 but lllater find out it requires 10.6.2 which i can't get for some reason. i just wanted to know where can i get (exact link if pssible) compatible version of iphone sdk for mac 10.5.8 ... no matter its iphone sdk 3.0 or 3.1 3.2... pls guide.. t hanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [i want some link from where i can download the iphone sdk 3.1 .](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786601/i-want-some-link-from-where-i-can-download-the-iphone-sdk-3-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.2 did not have a Leopard compatible version.

XCode 3.1.4 with the OS 3.1.3 SDK is Leopard compatible.  You can download it here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.1.3__final/iphone_sdk_3.1.3_with_xcode_3.1.4__leopard__9m2809a.dmg