# iphone force upgrade to 3.2 instead of 4.0

Tags: iphone

My iPhone is running OS 3.1.3.  I am running xcode 3.2.3 which only supports the iPhone OS 3.2 and 4.0, so I need to upgrade my iPhone's OS to 3.2.  (I don't want to upgrade to 4.0 for obvious reasons.)

But in itunes, when I click "check for updates" it detects the existence of iOS 4.0 so it doesn't offer me to upgrade to 3.2, only 4.0.  Is there a way to force the upgrade to 3.2?

The other possible solution I see is installing a second version of xcode (3.2.2 or something which supports the older versions of the iPhone OS?)

God I hate apple and their compatibility issues.

Comment: NOT a programming related question. Read the rules before posting!

Comment: What is the 'obvious' reason that you don't want to upgrade to 4.0? It is the new standard now.

Comment: @Emil: iPhone 2G compatibility?

Comment: related to iphone development, though.  i'm NOT just a random user trying to find out how to upgrade to the latest and greatest version of the iPhone OS.  I think this is a reasonable question.

Comment: i mean, its public release was yesterday. given that apple doesn't let me downgrade my iphone OS, I'm reticent to upgrade until it seems safe.  also i want my apps to be compatible with phones with 3.0...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install 3.2 on iPhones / iPod Touches, since 3.2 is for iPad only.

You could try to change the "iPhone OS Deployment Target" to 3.1.3 in the Project Info. See also [Where can I download the older iPhone OS 3.1 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786601/i-want-some-link-from-where-i-can-download-the-iphone-sdk-3-1) for some links to older SDKs if you need them.

Comment: yeah, the problem is that xcode 3.2.3 removes targets below iOS 3.2.  So 3.1.3 is not an option.  I installed a separate version of the old xcode (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed) and that seemed to work.