# Base SDK of Xcode 3.2.2 does not include iOS, where'd it go?

Tags: iphone, xcode, backwards-compatibility, xcode3.2

So as of this writing, the newest version of Xcode is 3.2.5 (though the GM seed of Xcode 4 was just released, still not ready to make that jump). I know Apple graciously decided to stop allowing developers the ability to test their apps in simulator for any OS below 4.* with the past few releases of Xcode.

I know I need at least Xcode 3.2.2 to test legacy OS versions of the iPhone in the simulator (3.*).

I install Xcode 3.2.2 in a folder on the same level of the current 3.2.5 version. After the install, I opened my project that has no issues in the newest version of Xcode.

I go to the project settings and check the Base SDK value. Under that tab there is no option for the iPhone OS. All it allows me are Current Mac OS and Mac OS X 10.5 and 10.6.

I check the current Target Tab and see the same issue. No iPhone OS options.

The PDF that comes with the xcode322_2148_developerdvd.dmg file (downloaded from Apple's repository http://connect.apple.com/) talks about the iPhone and iPad platforms, so I know this is a new enough version.

What is it that I am missing?

**Edit:**

After looking through what was installed on my system with xcode322_2148_developerdvd.dmg, it appears that Apple left out all of the necessary files for the iPhone portion of Xcode. Guess it's off to Google to find an old, complete version of Xcode. Unless someone here has a good virus free location they are willing to suggest :)

Comment: Are you sure that you downloaded the 3.2.2 version of Xcode that comes with the iOS SDK, from the iPhone Developer Center? The base Xcode doesn't necessarily come with the iOS SDK.

Comment: Now that I look at it, the older Xcode versions you download from connect.apple.com are without the iOS SDK.  This question asks something similar, and the answer has links to the direct download locations of Apple's older SDK versions: [Where can I download the older iPhone OS 3.1 SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786601/where-can-i-download-the-older-iphone-os-3-1-sdk)